# Open Windows Explorer tab in background

Tags: windows-explorer

Windows Explorer FINALLY supports tabs (and using middle-click to open them), and now supports dragging a tab out of one window to create a new window. I'd like the LAST function that was introduced with web browsers.

Does anyone know how to middle-click on a folder in Windows Explorer and have it open in the background instead of immediately switching to the new tab?

Comment: There isn’t a setting or a mouse shortcut that allows this to be possible